# Understanding Python logger performance with redaction filter

Tags: python, performance, logging, filter, formatter

to prevent sensitive information from being logged I've added a redaction filter to my logger file handler. For this, I've created a formatter with a function that replaces substrings in the log message with "***" when the substring is equal to one of the elements in the pattern list.

This works completely fine.

Now I was curious about the performance impact when searching for my patterns (up to 40 chars in length) in every single log line and replacing the substring whenever necessary.

I've timed 100 times logging 10.000 very long messages + long custom attributes (I use json.formatter).

```
for i == 1 to 100:  (I want to see the average time for 10000 lines when running 100 times)
  startTime = ...
  for j == 1 to 10000:
    Log("veeeeeery long string...")
  duration = now - starttime
```

I timed 3 scenarios:
a) without redaction filter
b) with redaction filter (but nothing needs to be replaced)
c) with redaction filter and replacing substrings like hell

To my surprise, it does not make a difference (measuring the time for the loops where the messages get logged).

Why is that? Does the logging formatter run in a kind of separate process?
Or why does this additional searching/replacing not harm the runtime in the "main" thread?

Comment: Was anything actually output in your test? If log levels etc forbid logging from actually happening, formatting and filtering isn't run either.

Comment: Yes. My logfile contains every single line of logs. And when using the option c) - also all substrings that are part of the pattern list are successfully replaced with " *** "

Comment: Well, the formatter for sure doesn't run in a separate process and unless you're using a `threading.handlers.QueueListener` somewhere, there's no multi-threading going on. Would it be possible that your redaction filter is simply efficient?

Comment: Writing the logs to file is probably the issue here. I would guess that this tests spends 99% of its time doing disk operations, so the performance of the Formatter doesn't show up, even if it is slower than not having it.